# sap.m.TimePickerSliders behave unexpectedly on mobile devices

Tags: sapui5

On iOS Safari, the time picker sliders from the `sap.m` namespace behave unexpectedly. When you select a value at a slider, you have to tap on a different one in order to "really select" the previous value. This even applies to the [example in the Demo Kit](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.81.2/#/entity/sap.m.TimePickerSliders/sample/sap.m.sample.TimePickerSliders).

E.g. if you want to select 9:41am, I would usually select 9 at the hours slider, tap on the minutes slider in order to confirm the hour selection and change the minutes to 41. Then I would (w/o tapping a different slider) press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button to close the dialog and display the output on the page. On iOS Safari, however, you have to tap another slider (e.g. the am/pm one) after the last selection in order to confirm the minutes selection. Otherwise it will apparently not detect that the minutes slider has been changed and only update the hours on the page.

If you have any idea on how to fix this, I would love to hear your answer :)

Comment: The issue is reproducible on all non-desktop devices. Also [this LOC](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/dcadb619081ac40c490d7537697d0541e539b5f6/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/TimePickerSlidersRenderer.js#L45) causes an error log in the console. Not sure if that's the actual reason for the behavior. I'd suggest to [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new) as it affects all UI5 apps.

Comment: Although my colleague tested it on his iPad and there it worked fine. But is the iPad a desktop or non-desktop device (thinking of the what is a computer ad)?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on iPads using Chromium's device emulator within the devtools as I don't own any iOS devices. But I guess the real devices behave differently. My real Android phone could also reproduce it.

Comment: The issue is no longer reproducible:  https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3003

Comment: You mean the issue was closed. It’s still not fixed in the latest version of the demo kit, but you can fix it by calling the ``collapseAll()`` method on the time picker sliders. I’ll provide a working version later.

Comment: It's fixed in the latest version: https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.TimePickerSliders/sample/sap.m.sample.TimePickerSliders

Comment: Ah ok, I didn’t know about the nightly version. This makes totally sense. Do you know when this version will be released?

Comment: The fix is now included in 1.84.0 which is the current OpenUI5 stable version. The issue is no longer reproducible.